# How to match the following?

Tags: regex, parsing

The data I want to parse has columns with the following format:

```
Character   Big Medium  Meaning ImageCode   Small   Constitutens    Lesson  Frame   Strokes JH  JTPL    Heisig Story    koohiiStory1    koohiiStory2    On-Reading  Kun-Reading Examples:
```

All of those are separated by tabs `\t` (even though it may not look like it on the browser). Also notice at the end of each line there is a colon `:`. The problem is that the columns `koohiiStory2` and `examples` may or may not exist and there may also be cases in which the data is corrupt and there is a tab inside `Heisig Story` but those are the minority.

What I'm trying to match is the values for `On-Reading`, `Kun-Reading` and `Examples`. All of these are distinct from the rest because they don't use standard english characters (romaji) but they use japanese characters instead with the exception of perhaps a few commas or dots. It is also guaranteed that either `Kun-Reading` or `Examples` will end with a colon `:` and that `On-Reading` and `Kun-Reading` will exist and that all three of the columns will be consecutive.

Here is some [sample data](http://pastebin.com/raw/JkGTCMpN).

How can I parse that to return [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/2ahqyQFY)?

Comment: You should add in your question the real data (separated by the tabs) When we copy it to process it is all spaces separated. You need to format it accordingly what you state so it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: @Jorge Campos not sure how to do that, it just seems to change my tabs for spaces no matter what... hold on I'll see if I can use pastebin or something.

Comment: @Jorge Campos pastebin isn't working either...

Comment: It will be difficult to find the right columns since it is not formated equaly I suggest you (which know the data) to format it as `Character\tBig\tMedium  Meaning\tImageCode\tSmall` instead, that way we can copy the data and replace it by tabs easily

Comment: @Jorge Campos Links should now have data with the proper formatting.

Comment: Well I solved it in a very simple way that I don't know if it would be good for you. Trying to understand the data I pasted it into Excel (since it is tab separated it will create a column to each data) So, for your column that may or may not have the data on it I just pushed it into the right, then removed all unnecessary previous columns. The final result is excatly the data you posted as result.

Comment: This works for me `(?<=([a-zA-Z0-9]|[^\w])\.(\s|\t))([^\w]+)(?=\:)`. Are those result letters hiragana, katagana or kanji or..? I am trying to expand it though.

Comment: @Jorge Campos that very strange, there should be cases such as the one for the 'seven' character where 15th column (as well as possibly others) should have the value for koohiiStory2 instead of On-Reading like most other entries...

Comment: @choz The expression you posted is not working for me with the sample data I provided. I've tested it locally using notepad++ and also [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) although it might be the case I'm testing it wrong. The examples column contains kanji, hiragana and katakana in most cases; on-reading and kun-reading contain katakana and hiragana respectively, and exclusively.

Comment: I tested it using `pcre` on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it worked. I'll test it again. But before, I can not seem to find `、` character in any all those kind of japanese letters. Any help?

Comment: @choz 、is an ideographic comma used exclusively in japanese and chinese I believe unicode U+3001 according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma). I have no idea how to escape that character if thats your question.

Comment: Actually, this is rather simpler than before. I tried `/(?<=\.(\s|\t))[^\w]+(?=\:)/g` and returns all 11 lines you expect. Please do check if it works, If it doesn't, please share in which language you use this regex for and which site you tested it. Btw, I've also found that `coma` [here](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/).

Comment: @choz the expression `(?<=\.(\s|\t))[^\w]+(?=\:)` only matches a single tab before first expression it should be matching, perhaps I'm totally clueless. Heres the [link](https://regex101.com/r/dG3yX3/1). I'm downloading and installing `prec`. I'm not using any lenguage atm I'm just trying to clean the data before storing in a database or some other place.

Comment: You forgot to put global parameter. It should be `/(?<=\.(\s|\t))[^\w]+(?=\:)/g`, and it works just fine. [Look here](https://regex101.com/r/dG3yX3/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I'll give it a shot.

Since the content you expect is mostly *non-ascii* characters within a `dot + space or tab* and :`

```
(?<=\.(\s|\t)) // Positive lookbehind for a 'dot' + 'space or tab'
[^\w]+ // Any non words
(?=\:) // Positive lookahead for a ':'
```

[Working sample on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dG3yX3/2)

[image]

Comment: I think I'm an idiot but I can't get the results from group 0 of each match? I see they're highlighted though.

Comment: @MrD How are you getting it?

Comment: using your link, match information shows only tabs (group 1) and exports only those aswell

Comment: @MrD Just added an image to confirm if that's what you're seeing?

Comment: You should provide how you're using "that" tool actually. But, try this now `/(?<=\.\t)([^\w]+)(?=\:)/g`. This should make them in group 1.